# Проблема со спринг-бутом

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, controller

Не могли бы вы, пожалуйста, подсказать, я изучал spring boot, и в ходе проекта мне понадобилось собрать данные с одного контроллера, и обработать их относительно присланных данных другого контроллера внутри основного файла "ExampleApplication". Только возникла проблема, как достать эти значения, ведь сами классы контроллеров создаются внутри метода "run".
Вот код:

ExampleApplication.java

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.example.StudyGrid.controller"})
public class ExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StudyGridApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

FirstController.java

```java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;


@Controller
public class MainController {


    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public String welcomepage() {
        return "home";
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title","Главная страница");
        return "home";
    }
    @GetMapping("/signup")
    public String error(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title","Регистрация");
        return "reg";
    }
    @GetMapping("/error")
    public String error2(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title","Главная страница");
        return "error";
    }

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public String signup(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return "";
    }

}
```

Второй контроллер такой же.

Comment: Вопрос не совсем понятен. Вам нужно отработать один метод контроллера, при этом отработав другой метод другого контроллера?

Comment: @ArturVartanyan Я получаю какую-то переменную в методе пост при рекуетспарам. В обеих контроллерах так. То что мы получили записаны в переменные внутри классов контроллеров.Мне нужно их получить и обработать в главном файле. Проблема в том, что эти классы создаются методом ран. И я не знаю как их оттуда "достать"

Comment: честно, все равно не понял ничего

Comment: @ArturVartanyan если быть проще, то как создать уровень, где находится вся бизнес логика сайта (как этот уровень будет брать данные из контроллеров?) при помощи базы данных?

Comment: Возможно, если мы поняли друг-друга, проблема в вашем понимании уровней. На самом низком уровне условное БД, после него на уровень выше сервис, а выше сервиса только контроллер. Поэтому не совсем понятно, зачем сервису брать контроллер, если должно быть наоборот.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо! Я просто новичек, буквально вчера взялся за спринг бут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpringApplication.run() - возвращает ApplicationContext контекст.Так как аннотация @Controller наследует аннотацию @Component, то контроллеры будут опубликованы в контексте.